# replace NaN to NA in tibble using mutate

Tags: r, tidyverse

Convert NaN to NA in tibble using mutate

```
tbl = tibble(x = c(NaN, NaN, 2, 3, 4, NA, NA, NaN, 5))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will change all `NaN`s to `NA` in all numeric columns.

```
tbl %>% mutate(across(where(is.numeric), \(x) ifelse(is.nan(x), NA, x)))
# # A tibble: 9 × 1
#       x
#   <dbl>
# 1    NA
# 2    NA
# 3     2
# 4     3
# 5     4
# 6    NA
# 7    NA
# 8    NA
# 9     5
```